# How to do notifications in PHP?

Tags: php, notifications

How can I show users that they have a new message or response awaiting in their inbox by showing them a number or text telling them to check it and then only remove the notification automatically if the user responds to it or clicks "done" (meaning no further response necessary).

Comment: Most use sessions to handle this now. The only "thinking" part about this, is how to NOT send the user more than one notification pertaining to a new message in their inbox. A "read" flag would suffice.

Comment: The question is just too vague. Do you have problems in the way you should store information about unread messages in the DB? Are you familiar with technologies such as Javascript/AJAX to make the notifications working? Could you elaborate a bit more on which part of your task you have problems with and on which is your knowledge level?

Answer (score 3):

I assume the messages will be stored in a DB. Just add a 'read' boolean column and then query the DB for unread messages to know whether there are new messages.

When the user replies you set the read column to 1.

Comment: +1 but I would use a datetime column: null for "unread" and a date for when the message was first read.

Comment: @chelmertz: that could be helpful in certain situations. I guess it depends on the specific case, the question here is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

if you wan't something like on facebook, and other social network sites, U need to use javascript to do this. Php is serverside language, and that can;t do.

if you don't ask that, and u are only interested how to solve this with php and database.
Try to make new row. Called status, and update table set that coloumn is 1 if is read, 0 if isn't read...

Answer (score 0):

This really needs javascript.  Basically you have javascript make a request every x amount of seconds to a php page that checks for new notifications. Then the javascript alerts the user.

Comment: He/she doesn't need JavaScript. Although, it's fancier to alert to user instantly.

Comment: Notifications are obviously meant to be instant.